# matplotlib.pyplot.legend() returns empty

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

Hi I am working on winkosisn breast cancer dataset. I have applied PCA on it and stored the result in df1. df2 contains the labels of class type obtained when applied KMeans. Then I concatenated both df1 and df2.

To visualise the result, I have used matplotlib. The data points as well as cluster centers are plotted but the legend is not showing.It just returns empty.

Can anyone tell why does this happen?

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame(x_trans,columns=['Feature1','Feature2'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data = km.labels_,columns=['Breast_Cancer_Type'])
df3 = pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1)
print(df3)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.scatter(df3.iloc[:,0],df3.iloc[:,1],c=km.labels_,cmap='rainbow')
plt.scatter(km.cluster_centers_[:,0],km.cluster_centers_[:,1],color='black')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to add label in `plt.scatter()` function. see these [examples](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/scatter_with_legend.html)